# Pointer variable used without initialization C Visual

Tags: c, visual-studio, pointers, compiler-errors, initialization

```
void main(){
float a = 5;
float *test;
*test = a;
}
```

This doesn't compile. Why? I mean there is instantly a bug that pointer variable cannot be used without initializaiton.

Here's a link to the error https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWCVY.png

Comment: Please show the actual compiler error.

Comment: added a link in the main post

Comment: Are you sure you don't want test = &a; ?

Comment: @Greyshack You obviously compiled the code....

Comment: Yeah I know it's compiled, I used the wrong word sorry ;d I don't know how to call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void main(){
float a = 5;
float *test;  // now the pointer test contains a random value
              // and because it can be anything it is not safe to access that memory
*test = a;    // not safe!. Dereferencing a random address will give garbage.
}
```

Use `test = &a` if you want the pointer to have the address of the variable a.

Answer (score 1):

```
test = &a;
```

The thing is when you declare the pointer variable, it doesn't get an address, but it's a variable address. So if you have to change directly the address, using what I've write at the first line.

Using `*test` will change the content (so if *test = 1 and a = 2, when you do `*test = a`, the content of test will be 2). Because there's no content at the declaration of *test, you can't modify something that just doesn't exist.

after, a little trick to be more efficient (and so haven't to create pointer like you do) :

```
void function(int *a); /* declaration */
function(&a); /* call */
```

when you modify "a" in the function, it'll be modify in the main because of the address : you change the content, not the container.

```
*a = 1;
```

in the main you'll now have a == 1

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because at that point the pointer doesn't point to anything (dangling pointer), still you tell it to assign the value found in a wherever he's pointing. And this is the problem. It can't assign a value to nothing.

You have to give it the address of a variable to point at. After that you can deference it and assign values to that variable with the help of the pointer.